# Allow non registered users to view content with pundit

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-4.2, pundit

I have having trouble allowing non-registered/non-logged in users to view the index and show pages for a blog section. I am using Pundit for authorization and realize that at the moment I have my policies set to not allow non-users to view any part of the blog section, but I have no idea how to work around that to have no policy for the index and show page.

My goal is to have the following:

> Allow Admin and Editors to view, create, edit, and delete blogs

This portion works pefect

> Allow registered users to view blogs

This portion works perfect

> Allow non-registered/non-logged in users to view blogs

**This part does not work**

When I try to view the index page as a non-registered/non-logged in user, I will get an access denied flash message that comes out of my application controller, which is doing what it is supposed to be doing given the current policies.

So my question is: How do I modify my policies to allow non-registered/non-logged in users to view the index and show pages only?

**Application Controller**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include Pundit
  rescue_from Pundit::NotAuthorizedError, with: :user_not_authorized

  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  private

    def user_not_authorized(exception)
      flash[:danger] = "Access denied. You are not authorized to view that page."
      redirect_to (request.referrer || root_path)
    end


protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :password, :remember_me) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update) {|u| u.permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)}
  end


end
```

**Application Policy**

```
class ApplicationPolicy
  attr_reader :user, :record

  def initialize(user, record)
    raise Pundit::NotAuthorizedError, "You must be logged in to perform this action" unless user
    @user = user
    @record = record
  end

  def index?
    true
  end

  def show?
    scope.where(:id => record.id).exists?
  end

  def create?
    false
  end

  def new?
    create?
  end

  def update?
    false
  end

  def edit?
    update?
  end

  def destroy?
    false
  end

  def scope
    Pundit.policy_scope!(user, record.class)
  end

  class Scope
    attr_reader :user, :scope

    def initialize(user, scope)
      @user = user
      @scope = scope
    end

    def resolve
      scope
    end
  end
end
```

**Post Policy**

```
class PostPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  attr_reader :post

  class Scope < Scope
    def resolve
      if user&.admin?&.editor?&.user?
        scope.all
      else user != admin? || editor? || user?
        scope
      end
    end
  end

  def permitted_attributes
    if user.admin? || user.editor?
      [:title, :body, :image, :permalink, :description, :tag_list, :username]
    else
      [:title, :body, :image, :username]
    end
  end

  def index?
    true
  end

  def show?
    true
  end

  def new?
    user.admin? || user.editor?
  end

  def create?
    user.admin? || user.editor?
  end

  def update?
    user.admin? || user.editor?
  end

  def destroy?
    user.admin? || user.editor?
  end
end
```

**Post Controller**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  after_action :verify_authorized, only: [:destroy]

  def index
    @meta_title = "Blog"
    @meta_description = "page description here"
    @posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 4)
  end

  def show
    @meta_title = @post.title
    @meta_description = @post.description
  end

  def new
    @meta_title = "Add New Blog"
    @meta_description ="Add a new blog."
    @post = Post.new
    authorize @post
  end

  def edit
    @meta_title = "Edit Blog"
    @meta_description ="Edit an existing blog."
    authorize @post
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new
    @post.update_attributes(permitted_attributes(@post))
    @post.user = current_user if user_signed_in?

    authorize @post

    if @post.save
      redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    if @post.update_attributes(permitted_attributes(@post))
      authorize @post
      redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.'
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    if @post.present?
      @post.destroy
      authorize @post
    else
      skip_authorization
    end

    redirect_to posts_url, notice: 'Post was successfully deleted.'
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_post
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow the white list through.
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(policy(@post).permitted_attributes)
    end
end
```

I've seen a similar question asked [Pundit policy_scoper error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35508904/pundit-policy-scope-error-undefined-method-admin-for-nilnilclass), but the solution suggested there does not seem to work in my case.

Comment: It looks like it shouldn't even be hitting your policy from the index or show actions since you aren't calling `authorize` in either action. What happens if you add `authorize Post` to your index action? I would think since you are returning true in PostPolicy.index? that it should work.

Comment: Hi @scott I tried both <authorize Post> and <authorize @post>. <Post> had no effect and <@post> created an error <Pundit::NotDefinedError>. <@post> works for the all other actions in the index as you can see in the controller.

Comment: @Scott do you have any other ideas or insights? I am still struggling to get past this issue. I've tried everything from adding in `skip_authorization` in the index to deleting the index and show def's out of the policy for posts and then both posts and application policies. No matter what I still get the "Not authorized" flash message when trying to access as a non-logged in/guest user.

Comment: Do you have this code in a public repo I could pull down?

Comment: Unfortunately it's in a private bitbucket as it's a live site for a client (learning project for me), but I could invite you in on a read access.

Comment: my email is solsen300 at gmail

Comment: I've added you on as a reader if you haven't already received notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much frustration, I was finally able to solve the issue. Big thanks go out to @Scott for helping get the controller and testing set up as they should be, and nearly getting the policies working.

Turns out that the `raise Pundit::NotAuthorizedError, "must be logged in" unless user` in the `initializer` section of the `Application Policy` was not allowing non-logged-in users from accessing the index page (just like it's supposed to when you want a closed system...). Since my application is open for anyone to view in the index and show pages of the blog, I needed to remove that line.

Once removed the application would then throw a `undefined method admin?' for nil:NilClass` for non-logged-in users trying to access the blog index page. This was solved by using the correct conventions of identifying users in `Post Policy`. For each def in the policy I had `user.admin? || user.editor?`. That needed to be changed to `user&.admin? || user&.editor?`.

The code ended up as follows:

**Application Policy**

```
    class ApplicationPolicy
  attr_reader :user, :record

  def initialize(user, record)
    @user = user
    @record = record
  end

  def index?
    false
  end

  def show?
    scope.where(:id => record.id).exists?
  end

  def create?
    false
  end

  def new?
    create?
  end

  def update?
    false
  end

  def edit?
    update?
  end

  def destroy?
    false
  end

  def scope
    Pundit.policy_scope!(user, record.class)
  end

  class Scope
    attr_reader :user, :scope

    def initialize(user, scope)
      @user = user
      @scope = scope
    end

    def resolve
      scope
    end
  end
end
```

**Post Policy**

```
class PostPolicy < ApplicationPolicy

  attr_reader :post


  class Scope < Scope
    def resolve
      if user&.admin? || user&.editor?
        scope.all
      else 
      end
    end
  end

  def permitted_attributes
    if user.admin? || user.editor?
      [:title, :body, :image, :permalink, :description, :tag_list, :username]
    else
      [:title, :body, :image, :username]
    end
  end

  def index?
    true
  end

  def show?
    true
  end

  def new?
    admin_or_editor
  end

  def create?
    admin_or_editor
  end

  def update?
    admin_or_editor
  end

  def destroy?
    admin_or_editor
  end

  private

  def admin_or_editor
    user&.admin? || user&.editor?
  end
end
```

**Post Controller**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
  after_action :verify_authorized, except: [:index, :show]

  def index
    @meta_title = "Blog"
    @meta_description = "blog description"
    @posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 4)
  end

  def show
    @meta_title = @post.title
    @meta_description = @post.description
  end

  def new
    @meta_title = "Add New Blog"
    @meta_description ="Add a new blog."
    @post = Post.new
    authorize @post
  end

  def edit
    @meta_title = "Edit Blog"
    @meta_description ="Edit an existing blog."
    authorize @post
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new
    @post.update_attributes(permitted_attributes(@post))
    @post.user = current_user if user_signed_in?

    authorize @post

    if @post.save
      redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    authorize @post
    if @post.update_attributes(permitted_attributes(@post))
      redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.'
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    if @post.present?
      @post.destroy
      authorize @post
    else
      skip_authorization
    end

    redirect_to posts_url, notice: 'Post was successfully deleted.'
  end

  private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Only allow the white list through.
  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(policy(@post).permitted_attributes)
  end
end
```